# Postfix/Dovecot: SASL LOGIN authentication aborted

Tags: email, postfix, log-files, dovecot, sasl

I use Postfix together with Dovecot (auth/LMTP) on my mailserver.
Everything is working fine, but I notice several warnings in the log-files each day:

```
postfix/smtpd[4169]: warning: unknown[MY.HOME.IP]: SASL LOGIN authentication aborted
dovecot: auth: Warning: auth client 0 disconnected with 1 pending requests: EOF
```

What is causing this warning?
Is this warning a server or a client (Apple Mail) problem?

Comment: If it's a Apple Mail problem: test with others ;)

Comment: The log entries appear very irregularly and irrespective of anything I can control, so testing is difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error log means client aborted SASL authentication process after process connect to dovecot SASL service.

FYI, here the sample of SASL LOGIN transaction [from this page](http://www.fehcom.de/qmail/smtpauth.html).

```
S: 220 esmtp.example.com ESMTP
C: ehlo client.example.com
S: 250-esmtp.example.com
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-SIZE 255555555
S: 250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
C: auth login
S: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
C: avlsdkfj
S: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
C: lkajsdfvlj
S: 535 authentication failed (#5.7.1)
```

After client announce `auth login`, it needs to provide user and password in two separate transactions. Client may disconnect or send '*" command to aborting connection between `auth login` and server response (535 Authentication failed) state. When that happened:

- Postfix disconnect logs that event with `SASL LOGIN authentication aborted`
- Postfix disconnect from dovecot SASL service, [the dovecot also logs this event](http://dovecot.org/list/dovecot-cvs/2011-November/019388.html) with `auth client 0 disconnected with 1 pending requests: EOF`

**Solution**

Your server was fine. You need to track down who mail client who connect to your server. Unless your client was complain that (s)he can't send email, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. Now I can definitely sleep better :)